# Possible to calculate MD5 (or other) hash with buffered reads?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, hash, md5, buffer

I need to calculate checksums of quite large files (gigabytes).  This can be accomplished using the following method:

```
    private byte[] calcHash(string file)
    {
        System.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithm ha = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create();
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        byte[] hash = ha.ComputeHash(fs);
        fs.Close();
        return hash;
    }
```

However, the files are normally written just beforehand in a buffered manner (say writing 32mb's at a time).  I am so convinced that I saw an override of a hash function that allowed me to calculate a MD5 (or other) hash at the same time as writing, ie: calculating the hash of one buffer, then feeding that resulting hash into the next iteration.

Something like this: (pseudocode-ish)

```
byte [] hash = new byte [] { 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 };
while(!eof)
{
   buffer = readFromSourceFile();
   writefile(buffer);
   hash = calchash(buffer, hash);
}
```

hash is now sililar to what would be accomplished by running the calcHash function on the entire file.

Now, I can't find any overrides like that in the.Net 3.5 Framework, am I dreaming ?  Has it never existed, or am I just lousy at searching ?  The reason for doing both writing and checksum calculation at once is because it makes sense due to the large files.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You use the `TransformBlock` and `TransformFinalBlock` methods to process the data in chunks.

```
// Init
MD5 md5 = MD5.Create();
int offset = 0;

// For each block:
offset += md5.TransformBlock(block, 0, block.Length, block, 0);

// For last block:
md5.TransformFinalBlock(block, 0, block.Length);

// Get the has code
byte[] hash = md5.Hash;
```

Note: It works (at least with the MD5 provider) to send all blocks to `TransformBlock` and then send an empty block to `TransformFinalBlock` to finalise the process.

Comment: Ok, but +1 for also providing a reference!

Comment: Ay caramba!  There it is!  That was the function I was searching for.  Good to know I wasn't making it all up.  Thanks to Guffa and Rubens for providing the correct answer so promptly. +1 to you both, I will accept this answer because of the included code example.

Comment: Note that you can equivalently replace the second instance of `block` by `null` in the call to TransformBlock; you don't actually want any copying to occur; the output parameter isn't actually doing anything with respect to the hashing.

Comment: Also, TransformFinalBlock can take zero for the length.

Comment: Is it possible to transform the first X blocks of data, dump the state data and then continue the next blocks after restoring state on a new calculation?. Having 100GB file in a cloud solution, it would be nice to be able to not have to go over the hole file in one go. machines could recycle ect.

Comment: @pksorensen: I don't think so, I don't see any methods or properties for getting or setting the computional state of the MD5 object. In theory it's of course possible, but you might need to use a separate implementation of the algorithm so that you can add methods for handling the state.

Comment: TransformFinalBlock can take zero for the length BUT the input block can't be null and must be Array.Empty<byte>. Because .NET loves their pointless ArgumentNullExceptions.

Comment: @EmperorEto: I think that the reasoning here is that it's more consistent to always throw an `ArgumentNullException` when the argument is null, than to exclude the case where the length is zero and the array isn't actually needed.

Comment: @Guffa definitely not opening that can of worms 

Answer (score 49):

I like the answer above but for the sake of completeness, and being a more general solution, refer to the `CryptoStream` class.  If you are already handling streams, it is easy to wrap your stream in a `CryptoStream`, passing a `HashAlgorithm` as the `ICryptoTransform` parameter.

```
var file = new FileStream("foo.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write);
var md5 = MD5.Create();
var cs = new CryptoStream(file, md5, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
while (notDoneYet)
{
    buffer = Get32MB();
    cs.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
}
System.Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(md5.Hash));
```

You might have to close the stream before getting the hash (so the `HashAlgorithm` knows it's done).

Answer (score 5):

Seems you can to use `TransformBlock` / `TransformFinalBlock`, as shown in this sample: [Displaying progress updates when hashing large files](http://www.infinitec.de/post/2007/06/09/Displaying-progress-updates-when-hashing-large-files.aspx)

Comment: That link is dead, try this instead: http://www.infinitec.de/post/2007/06/09/Displaying-progress-updates-when-hashing-large-files.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Hash algorithms are expected to handle this situation and are typically implemented with 3 functions:

`hash_init()` - Called to allocate resources and begin the hash.
`hash_update()` - Called with new data as it arrives.
`hash_final()` - Complete the calculation and free resources.

Look at http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/md5.html or http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/sha.html for good, standard examples in C; I'm sure there are similar libraries for your platform.

Comment: Good answer, but the "where is it in .net?" part of the question remains open.

Comment: @Pascal:  See the 2 good answers below, both of which had been posted before your comment.

Answer (score 3):

I've just had to do something similar, but wanted to read the file asynchronously. It's using TransformBlock and TransformFinalBlock and is giving me answers consistent with Azure, so I think it is correct!

```
private static async Task<string> CalculateMD5Async(string fullFileName)
{
  var block = ArrayPool<byte>.Shared.Rent(8192);
  try
  {
     using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
     {
         using (var stream = new FileStream(fullFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, 8192, true))
         {
            int length;
            while ((length = await stream.ReadAsync(block, 0, block.Length).ConfigureAwait(false)) > 0)
            {
               md5.TransformBlock(block, 0, length, null, 0);
            }
            md5.TransformFinalBlock(block, 0, 0);
         }
         var hash = md5.Hash;
         return Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
      }
   }
   finally
   {
      ArrayPool<byte>.Shared.Return(block);
   }
}
```

Comment: What's `ArrayPool`?

Comment: OK got it: [`ArrayPool`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Buffers/src/System/Buffers/ArrayPool.cs), need to install package [`System.Buffers`](https://preview.nuget.org/packages/System.Buffers).

Comment: This is useful, but not a .net 3.5 solution