# System.OutofMemoryException throw while doing GZipStream Compression

Tags: c#, .net, out-of-memory, gzipstream

I am working in win forms. Getting errors while doing following operation.
It shows me `System.OutOfMemoryException` error when i try to run the operation around 2-3 times continuously. Seems .NET is not able to free the resouces used in operation. The file i am using for operation is quite big,  around **more than 500 MB.**

My sample code is as below. Please help me how to resolve the error.

```
try
{
   using (FileStream target = new FileStream(strCompressedFileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
   using (GZipStream alg = new GZipStream(target, CompressionMode.Compress))
   {
       byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes(strFileToBeCompressed);
       alg.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
       alg.Flush();
       data = null;
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Instead of `ReadAllBytes`, open source file and use its `Read` method in a loop

Comment: `ReadAllBytes` is the killer - this gets all your more than 500 MB to RAM

Comment: Which line exactly is causing the OOM exception?

Comment: byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes(strFileToBeCompressed);
The line where OOM comes

Comment: The accepted answer to your previous question still holds true http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12038694/reading-large-file-using-byte-gives-error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A very **rough example** could be

```
// destFile - FileStream for destinationFile 
// srcFile - FileStream of sourceFile
using (GZipStream gz = new GZipStream(destFile, CompressionMode.Compress))
{
     byte[] src = new byte[1024];
     int count = sourceFile.Read(src, 0, 1024);
     while (count != 0)
     {
         gz.Write(src, 0, count );
         count = sourceFile.Read(src, 0, 1024);
     }
}
// flush, close, dispose ..
```

So basically I changed your `ReadAllBytes` to read only *chunks of 1024 bytes.*

Comment: Yes, but CopyTo is easier. Also, use a larger buffer, like  `8*1024` .

Comment: Of course you are right Henk, but I do think amit can adapt this on his own. @CopyTo thx for the hint!

Answer (score 7):

Replace `ReadAllBytes` with [Stream.CopyTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd782932%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

```
using (FileStream target = new FileStream(strCompressedFileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
using (GZipStream alg = new GZipStream(target, CompressionMode.Compress))
{
    using (var fileToRead = File.Open(.....))
    {
        fileToRead.CopyTo(alg);
    }
}
```

Comment: That will automatically use a sensible buffer size, but if you want to specify a buffer size there is a CopyTo() overload to do so. It is not necessary IMO, just letting the OP know it's there. The default buffer size is just 4096.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use this method to compress file [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream.aspx)

```
    public static void Compress(FileInfo fileToCompress)
    {
        using (FileStream originalFileStream = fileToCompress.OpenRead())
        {
            using (FileStream compressedFileStream = File.Create(fileToCompress.FullName + ".gz"))
            {
               using (GZipStream compressionStream = new GZipStream(compressedFileStream, CompressionMode.Compress))
               {
                      originalFileStream.CopyTo(compressionStream);                                
               }
            }
        }
    }
```

usage:

```
string directoryPath = @"c:\users\public\reports";

DirectoryInfo directorySelected = new DirectoryInfo(directoryPath);

foreach (FileInfo fileToCompress in directorySelected.GetFiles())
{
    Compress(fileToCompress);
}
```