# Reading large file - System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown. in C#

Tags: c#

My file name is like "c3c81d9e-b390-4622-999c-eb74146afd10.dat" when I am uploading this file.
I don't want to change uploading logic. This file size is 1 GB.

My problem is that, when different user download same file at same time it throws exception - `System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown`.

My Code is as follows.(C#)

```
string path ="E:\Projects\testsite\Inetpub\wwwroot\Downloads";

byte[] FileContents;

FileContents = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
```

but it gives System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.

I used following solution from stack overflow.

[Reading large file using byte[] gives error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12038694/reading-large-file-using-byte-gives-error)

```
byte[] hashValue;
SHA1Managed hashString = new SHA1Managed();                            
using (FileStream f = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open))
{
  hashValue = hashString.ComputeHash(f);
  foreach (byte x in hashValue)
  {
    file.HexadecimalValue += String.Format("{0:x2}", x);
  }
}
```

but this `file.HexadecimalValue` is returning string with hash value.
How can I extract data from `file.HexadecimalValue` and passing to  `HttpContext.Current.Response`?
What is best solution for this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `File.ReadAllBytes` tried read all file into memory, so not use it for big file, use something that work with stream

Comment: what is `file` variable? do you mean `f`?

Comment: You should use some caching. This not only wipes away your memory problems, but it will also be a lot faster.

Comment: I wonder if you understand what second code snipped does. Method [`ComputeHash`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xa627k19(v=vs.110).aspx) calculates a hash (by reading from stream either byte by byte or by chunks), there are no *data*, what `foreach` does is converting hash value (bytes) into a string. Instead of `File.ReadAllBytes` you have to use [`FileStream.Read`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.io.filestream.read(v=vs.100).aspx) to read content in portions, which you are able to hold in the memory.

Comment: hello check my sollution it will help you....

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change the logic then there are two options you must check.

1. List item Your application should be 64bit
2. You are using .NetFramework 4.5 (with large object support)

This will enable you application to support very large object up to 2 GB.

You can enable large object support by changing the configuration file as below...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
    <runtime>
      <gcAllowVeryLargeObjects enabled="true" /> 
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

May be this will solve your problem.

Comment: No this is already in 32 bit because in this application we used some ASP screens.

Comment: In that case you have to do changes in the code like instead of loading all file at a time load it batch by batch etc. without changing code and keeping it 32 bit won't help

Comment: you must think about 64 bit as I know in such situation you need to have 64 bit application the 32 bit application always has limit of memory consumption.

Comment: Sorry Nil , its 64 bit application

Comment: OK Could you please then try the second option for enabling the large object support?

Comment: Sorry I don't have any code snippet but the configuration is shared with you if you need more information refer this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh285054%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Nil, if I have .NetFramework 4.0 then its not working. This is client test server.

Comment: nil, so it cant possible with other solution which is on .NetFramework 4.0?