# getting out of memory exception when list<data> is large

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a big list of data `list<data>` and when trying to serialize it, getting out of memory exception.

for less data, there is NO error. What is the reason and any fix for it?

```
return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list<data>, Formatting.None, new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
        });
```

> System.OutOfMemoryException: 'Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.'

Comment: "*What is the reason*" - likely too much data. How big is this list?

Comment: I have 800 items in list

Comment: Is this a large object graph? Meaning is each item going to produce a lot of json?

Comment: Yes. this is the case. class `data` has multiple sub list of `a`, 'b`', 'c'` as well

Comment: it's a lots of JSON, what is the limit?

Comment: Hi @user584018 once I had your same problem and I solved by following this guide: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21038190/reading-large-file-system-outofmemoryexception-exception-of-type-system-outo. So by using a .NET framework > 4.5 and adding to the config file the possibilities of store large file

Comment: In all honesty, you shouldn't be trying to *allocate* things of that size in memory as they get *allocated* on the *Large Object Heap* (LOB), in-turn making it hard for the *GC* to compact and find free space (among other things). You should ideally, do this in *streams* directly to the file or IO source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into same OutOfMemory issue. I am using below code to serialize.

```
public void WriteJsonWithStream<T>(T items, string fileName)
{
using(TextWriter textWriter = File.CreateText(fileName))
  {
   var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
   serializer.Serialize(textWriter,items);
   textWriter.Flush();
  }
}
```

it basically uses JsonSerializer instead of JsonConvert.