# How to monitor status while hashing a file?

Tags: c#, progress-bar, backgroundworker, status

I'm building a small app that calculate hash from any given file to multiple types of hashing algorithm.

For simplicity sake I will focus on only 1 algorithm which is processor intensive and even if file is around 15mb it takes about half a minute to calculate the hash.

I am running the calculation by using BackgroundWorker (I'm not sure if that a right approach for a calculation but I'm just experimenting).

Now, I want to have a progress bar which will display hashing progess but I don't know how to get the maximum value needed nor where to put DoStep method.

Any ideas?

My code:

```
private void btnBrowse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ofdBrowse.Filter = "All Files|*.*";
    ofdBrowse.Title = "Open file.";

    if (ofdBrowse.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        txtPath.Text = ofdBrowse.FileName;

        bwWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
}

private void bwWorker_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    t5 = hash.HashSHA512(txtPath.Text);
}

void bwWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    txtSHA512.Text = t5;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to be able to monitor the progress, you will have to do the hash in small increments. You will then be able to calculate the percentage of the file that is done your self.

The building blocks for this would be [`HashAlgorithm.TransformBlock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hashalgorithm.transformblock.aspx) and [`HashAlgorithm.TransformFinalBlock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hashalgorithm.transformfinalblock.aspx).

Call `TransformBlock` in a loop, and use events, or [`BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.reportprogress.aspx) to communicate progress to the UI.

This [older question has an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124468/possible-to-calculate-md5-or-other-hash-with-buffered-reads/2124500#2124500) with a good example of using `TransformBlock`, and there is also an example in the docs for  [`TransformBlock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hashalgorithm.transformblock.aspx).

Comment: I added a link to an example.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend that you do not reference UI objects in your DoWork event.  You should correct your code to something like:

```
bwWorker.RunWorkerAsync(ofdBrowser.FileName);
....
void bwWorker_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    string filename = (string)e.Argument;
    ...
    e.Result = hash;
}

void bwWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    String hash = (string)e.Result;
    ...
}
```

I wish you good luck with your small app.

Comment: This is a good point. And thanks, some luck will be needed :)