# How to hash a single file multiple ways at same time?

Tags: c#, cryptography, hash

I'm trying to design a simple application to be used for calculating a file's CRC32/md5/sha1/sha256/sha384/sha512, and I've run into a bit of a roadblock. This is being done in C#.

I would like to be able to do this as efficiently as possible, so my original thought was to read the file into a memorystream first before processing, but I soon found out that very large files cause me to run out of memory very quickly. So it would seem that I have to use a filestream instead. The problem, as I see it, is that only one hash function can be run at a time, and doing so with a filestream will take a while for each hash to complete.

How might I go about reading a small bit of a file into memory, processing it with all 6 algorithms, and then going onto another chunk... Or does hashing not work that way?

This was my original attempt at reading a file into memory. It failed when I tried to read a CD image into memory prior to running the hashing algorithms on the memorystream:

```
    private void ReadToEndOfFile(string filename)
    {
        if (File.Exists(filename))
        {
            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(filename);
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];

            //double step = Math.Floor((double)fi.Length / (double)100);

            this.toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Reading File...";
            this.toolStripProgressBar1.Maximum = (int)(fs.Length / buffer.Length);
            this.toolStripProgressBar1.Value = 0;

            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                int read;
                while ((read = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                    this.toolStripProgressBar1.Value += 1;
                }

                _ms = ms;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're most of the way there, you just don't need to read the whole thing into memory at once.

All of the hashes in .Net derive from the [HashAlgorithm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hashalgorithm.transformblock.aspx) class. This has two methods on it: `TransformBlock` and `TransformFinalBlock`. So, you should be able to read a chunk for your file, stuff it into the TransformBlock method of whichever hashes you want to use, and then move into the next block. Just remember to call `TransformFinalBlock` for your last chunk from the file, as that is what gets you the byte array containing the hash.

For now, I would just do each hash one at a time, until it's working, then worry about running the hashes concurrently (using something like the Task Parallel Library)

Comment: I've tried getting this to work using MD5, and the program runs, though it appears to be generating incorrect hashes.

Here's a link to my code: [link](http://pastebin.com/i3iPwYZv)

Comment: You should be using `read` instead of `buffer.Length` when calling `TransformFinalBlock`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was agonizing over this for a while last night. Ended up hacking together something stupid looking to get it to work, but I couldn't help but feel that it was unnecessary.

I found out that it was because the last array was being fully read even when the last chunk was too small for it. I ended up making it create a new byte array for the last piece to equal the size of the last chunk.

Answer (score 4):

Hash algorithms are designed in a way that you can calculate the hash value incrementally. You can find a C#/.NET example for that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2124500). You can easily modify the provided code to update multiple hash algorithm instances in each step.

Answer (score -1):

This might be a great opportunity to get your feet wet with the TPL data flow objects. Read the file in one thread and post the data to a `BroadcastBlock<T>`. The `BroadcastBlock<T>` will be linked to 6 different `ActionBlock<T>` instances. Each `ActionBlock<T>` will correspond to one of your 6 hash strategies.

```
var broadcast = new BroadcastBlock<byte[]>(x => x);

var strategy1 = new ActionBlock<byte[]>(input => DoHash(input, SHA1.Create()));
var strategy2 = new ActionBlock<byte[]>(input => DoHash(input, MD5.Create()));
// Create the other 4 strategies.

broadcast.LinkTo(strategy1);
broadcast.LinkTo(strategy2);
// Link the other 4.

using (var fs = File.Open(@"yourfile.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
using (var br = new BinaryReader(fs))
{
  while (br.PeekChar() != -1)
  {
    broadcast.Post(br.ReadBytes(1024 * 16));
  }
}
```

The `BroadcastBlock<T>` will forward each chunk of data to all linked `ActionBlock<T>` instances.

Since your question focused more on how to get this all to occur concurrently I will leave the implementation of `DoHash` up to you.

```
private void DoHash(byte[] input, HashAlgorithm algorithm)
{
  // You will need to implement this.
}
```

Comment: This looks like a very interesting approach to multithreading. Shame it's in .net 4.5. For whatever reason, I have a hard enough time convincing myself to use .net 4.0, as it doesn't feel mainstream enough to me yet.

Comment: It seems this approach will not work. DoHash will be called for each input array of bytes. How should they be combined?

Comment: BroadcastBlock drops messages if his buffer full. That cuses wrong hash calculation if file read speed is higher than hashing speed.