# C# Exception 'System.OutOfMemoryException' In UWP

Tags: c#, exception, uwp

I am a Chinese, I am not very good at English. If I say something wrong, I say sorry to you. Thank you to answer my question.

In my UWP project, I want to calculate file's MD5. I use `FileOpenPicker` to choose file and `FileIO.ReadBufferAsync()` to convert the file to `IBuffer`, then I use `HashAlgorithmProvider.HashData()` to get the MD5 result. When I choosed small files, the program can run correctly, but I choosed large files(more than 1G), I got an exception, as described below

> System.OutOfMemoryException
>   Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program.

My computer's memory is 16GB, and the remaining memory is abundant.
What should I do?
Thanks!

Comment: Try use 64bit,the 32bit cant have a long stream.

Comment: Please share your actual code (a minimal but complete code sample that we can use to reproduce the problem).  If coded correctly, there is no reason to get an OOM no matter how large the file gets, and regardless of 32 vs 64 bit.

Comment: I think you have same problem with this link which already has solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13534334/how-to-compute-hash-md5-or-sha-of-a-large-file-with-c-sharp-in-windows-store-a

Comment: Thank you to answer my question.